# Rename columns using different rules

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas DataFrame:

```
df =
    --------------------
    0   1   2   3   4
    --------------------
    a   f   45  gt  0.9
    b   f   32  et  1.8
```

I need to rename columns from `0  1  2  3  4` to `f1  f2  f3  target  score`.

I can rename columns as follows:

```
df.columns = ["f1" "f2", "f3", "target", "score"]
```

However, if the number of columns is large, this approach is not suitable.

How can I automate the creation of `f1...fN`, and then renaming the specific columns (e.g. `3` and `4`) manually by index?

Comment: Looks like a simple `for` loop. Have you tried something lke that?

Comment: The new column container is simply a python-list. You can access this list at any index and modify the values.

Eventually, `df.columns = new_columns_list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is always 3+ columns use:

```
df.columns = [f'f{x+1}' for x in df.columns[:-2]] + ["target", "score"]
print (df)
  f1 f2  f3 target  score
0  a  f  45     gt    0.9
1  b  f  32     et    1.8
```

If should columns names starting by `f0`:

```
df = df.add_prefix('f')
df.columns.to_numpy()[-2:] = ["target", "score"]
print (df)
  f0 f1  f2 target  score
0  a  f  45     gt    0.9
1  b  f  32     et    1.8
```